# cellForRowAtIndexPath is not being called from custom class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using Xcode 7.0, Swift 2

I'm basically trying to create a custom class that will build a `UITable`, then in the `ViewController` I make a new object of the table and load it into self.view;

The problem I'm having is that the function `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` isn't being called at all from within the custom class. I've been looking for a solution for 3 days now and I've tried rebuilding the App and code several times with no luck.

Please note, if I use the same code (that is everything required to build the table; excluding init functions, etc) in the ViewController.swift file, it works fine.

I know the problem is with the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function because it will not print out the statement I set in that block of code when it runs. All other functions are called, but for some reason this isn't being called. Not sure if I overlooked something here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
class sideTest: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    let tesTable: UITableView = UITableView()
    var items: [String]?
    var mView: UIView = UIView()

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("The number of rows is: \(self.items!.count)")

        return self.items!.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        print("\nLets create some cells.")

        let sCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell!

        sCell.textLabel?.text = self.items![indexPath.row]
        sCell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkTextColor()

        return sCell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    }

    func tblSetup() {

        self.tesTable.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, mView.bounds.height)
        self.tesTable.delegate = self
        self.tesTable.dataSource = self

        self.tesTable.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()

        // load cells
        self.tesTable.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        self.tesTable.reloadData()

        print("Currenlty in tblSetup.\nCurrent rows is: \(self.items!.count)")
    }

    //Init

    override init() {
        super.init()

        self.items = nil

        self.tblSetup()
    }

    init(sourceView: UIView , itemListAsArrayString: [String]) {
        super.init()

        self.items = itemListAsArrayString
        self.mView = sourceView

        self.tblSetup()
    }
}
```

Here is the code from ViewController.swift; Please do note that the table gets built, but the cells do not populate, even if I manually enter cell info by doing: `sCell.textLabel?.text = "test cell"`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let myTable: sideTest = sideTest(sourceView: self.view, itemListAsArrayString: ["Cell 1", "Cell 2", "Cell 3"])
        self.view.addSubview(myTable.tesTable)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }   
}
```

Again, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You should definitely use the designated initializer of `UITableView` which is `init(frame frame: CGRect, style style: UITableViewStyle)` but I am not sure this will make the difference.

Comment: Is your class set as the data source of the table view?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your view controller don't have a strong reference to your sideTest var.
Once your view did load  finished,your sideTest is nil.Although you have a tableview(by add subview), but you no longer have a data source.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {}
```

is called after  view did load. That cause the problem.

change your view controller to:

```
    var tb :sideTest?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let myTable: sideTest = sideTest(sourceView: self.view, itemListAsArrayString: ["Cell 1", "Cell 2", "Cell 3"])
    print(myTable.tesTable.frame)
    tb=myTable
    self.view.addSubview(myTable.tesTable)
}
```

change your cellforrowatindexpath to:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    print("create cells")
    var cell :UITableViewCell?

    if let sCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell"){
       cell=sCell

    }else{
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    }


    cell!.textLabel?.text = self.items![indexPath.row]
    cell!.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkTextColor()

    return cell!
}
```

this will fix most of the problems.

Comment: Thank you so much. I hadn't even though about the strong reference. I really appreciate it. 
This worked like a charm. I can now move on. YAY!

Comment: Awesome, for me also datasource was getting cleared after viewdidload

Answer (score 3):

Your code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let myTable: sideTest = sideTest(sourceView: self.view, itemListAsArrayString: ["Cell 1", "Cell 2", "Cell 3"])
        self.view.addSubview(myTable.tesTable)
    }
```

I would think that the `myTable` variable goes out of scope and is released when viewDidLoad finishes, so there is no data source or delegate after that. Did you verify that the `self.view.addSubview(myTable.tesTable)` retains it? Try moving declaration of myTable outside of the function level (to property level) or add a diagnostic print to deinit..