# Only cellForRowAt indexPath not called all other dataSources and delegates are called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to make a framework and I am preferring everything in code so I figured out a way to do mostly everything but the main problem I am facing is I can't put the data in my table because `cellForRowAtIndexpath` is not getting called.

I have set `delegate` and `dataSource`.

I have added `numberOfRowsInSection` and it returns 10.

I have added `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and it returns 10.

I have added `cellForForAtIndexPath` and return a cell.

The main problem is that all these other methods are called as I have added print statements in all of them except `cellForForAtIndexPath`.

The problem is that I can't even try debugging because the method is not even called.

```
class PopControl: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    let tableView = UITableView()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("row selected")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("cell for row at index path called")
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "ABCD"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "EFGH"

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("number of rows in section called")
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        print("Height for row at index path called")
        return 10
    }

    func makeTable(){
        let vc = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.childViewControllers.last
        vc?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        print(vc)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        vc?.view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (vc?.view.topAnchor)!, constant: 100).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (vc?.view.bottomAnchor)!, constant: -20).isActive = true
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (vc?.view.leftAnchor)!, constant: 20).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (vc?.view.rightAnchor)!, constant: -20).isActive = true
        print("dataSource for tableView is")
        print(tableView.dataSource.debugDescription.description)
        print("delegate is")
        print(tableView.delegate.debugDescription.utf8CString)
    }
```

I am using it this way because I want to call the `makeTable()` function from a different class. What I mean is I don't have any intention of using this class as a `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`. I just want to use it to present the view controller with a table view from anywhere in the code.

Everything works but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not called. I mean tableView gets rendered but no cells are displayed.

Comment: If you want help with code that isn't working as expected then you need to [edit] your question to include relevant code that fully demonstrates the issue.

Comment: print statement inside `cellForRowAt` method gets called or not?

Comment: no, It doesn't get called that is the main problem I am struggling with.

Comment: Add the code that actually makes use of this `PopControl` class. Most likely you have a memory management issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cellForRowAtIndexPath is not being called from custom class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671905/cellforrowatindexpath-is-not-being-called-from-custom-class)

Comment: @karthikeyan let me check it.

Comment: Cell for row will only call if your tableview has height, check tableview height  in numberOfRows Method :)

Comment: @MikeAlter, Tried what you said yes the frame and bounds both of tableView were (0,0,0,0) but then I did that after just instantiating the tableVeiw and then they were (0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 736.0) but then also the actual problem hadn't solved cellForRowAtIndexPath wasn't called.

Comment: print(vc) what does it prints ?, and it is very wrong that you are initiate tableview in NSObject class . try to remove constraints  add static frame there on   makeTable method

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806402/dynamic-datasource-delegates-for-uitableview-in-swift) link may be helpful.

Comment: @karthikeyan This link helped in presenting the table view the way I want but the new problem I am facing is that as  I touch the cells or scroll them or do any activity then all the cells just vanish from the table view.

Comment: Kindly use dequesreusable cell

Comment: Finally everything solved.

Comment: Thanks. @karthikeyan it was a slight mistake from my side. Thanks so much man.

Comment: @user3745635 what was the issue?

Comment: @karthikeyan The issue was I was trying to reduce coupling so much that it was losing the references than what I did is that I created a ViewController and did all the code related to that table in that ViewController and then presented that ViewController wherever it was needed. Thanks once again.

Comment: you welcome have a nice day!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be not reusing cell, try to reuse your **UITableviewCell**

add follow code in `makeTable`

```
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

at `cellForRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
        let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"Cell") as UITableViewCell!

        // set the text from the data model
        cell.textLabel?.text = "ABC"

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Did you fix it?